# add grouping variable for nested tibbles

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

This is a follow-up to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383438/adding-grouped-variable-name-to-plot-with-group-nest-and-map).

I need to be able to group_by() columns in my new nested table. I can't find a purrr function that is does this (although I know a solution exists). I need to group_by in each table to apply additional summarizing functions and fit linear models appropriate. The example here is just a dummy example.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(2)
N <- 30
df <- tibble(type = rep(c("small","medium","high"), each=N/3),
             dummy = rep(c(1,5,10),each=10),
             xvals = rep(1:10,3),
             A = rnorm(N)*dummy,
             B = rnorm(N)*dummy,
             C = rnorm(N)*dummy) %>%
  mutate(type = factor(type, levels=c("small","medium","high"))) %>%
  select(-dummy) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-c(type,xvals), names_to="metric", values_to = "value") %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  group_nest(.key="data")
```

This produces a tibble with two columns:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  type   data             
  <fct>  <list>           
1 small  <tibble [30 x 3]>
2 medium <tibble [30 x 3]>
3 high   <tibble [30 x 3]>
```

This is an example of what I want to do across all the nested tibbles:

```
df[[2]][[1]] %>% 
  group_by(metric) %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(value))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  metric   mean
  <chr>   <dbl>
1 A       0.211
2 B      -0.296
3 C      -0.391
```

Comment: After the `group_nest` there are only two columns `type` and `data`

Comment: What exactly is the desired output? What does the tibble that you are trying to create look like? You can only group a tibble based on columns it has at the top level.

Comment: @akrun I updated the post based on your comments. It should be more clear now as to my intentions.

Comment: @LloydChristmas. You can check my upddate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `group_nest`, the 'data' is a `list` column of `tibble`s and there are only two columns 'type' and 'data'.  If we need to create a grouping based on the `list` column, loop through the `list` with `map` and then do the `group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
    mutate(data  = map(data, ~ .x %>%
                                   group_by(metric)  %>%
              summarize(mean = mean(value)))) -> out

out$data[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  metric   mean
#  <chr>   <dbl>
#1 A       0.115
#2 B       0.323
#3 C      -0.326
```

NOTE: Output values will be different as there was not `set` seed